# mysql driver not loading on flask_sqlalchemy python3 in venv | No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.9, mysql-connector-python

Im trying to make the following  combination work.
No luck. Anyone here can help ?

```
flask_sqlalchemy
mysqlclient
mysql-connector-python
```

Python 3.9.5
setup.cfg has above package and being installed in a **venv**

Error

```
    engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], echo = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Comment: This is not 'MySQL driver not loading'. This is "No module named 'MySQLdb'". Different issue. You don't have that Python module installed.

Answer (score 0):

venv had to be resourced in a shell environment. So packages installed were not in path.

Also, mysql-connector-python is not required in the above setup.

So much steps for a local isolated package installation scope.

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .

cp .env to instance/ 
flask run
```